# does google map chart support size of 750 by 400 pixels

Tags: google-visualization

I need to implement a javascript based world map with dynamic city markers which are clickable.
I need to know if google world map supports my size of 750  by 400 pixels? and also how can I generate city based markers which are clickable.

Thanks
Priyank